# SELECT WHERE OleDbException thrown

Tags: c#, t-sql

I've been struggling for half an hour now with this.

```
using(con)
{
   con.Open();    

   foreach(string category in categories)
   { 
      string select_cmd = "SELECT FileName FROM Songs WHERE MusicCategory=\'" + category + "\'";
      var cmd = new OleDbCommand(select_cmd, con);
      using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while(reader != null && reader.Read()
          {
             // do some work
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting an OleDbException:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '1stMusicType = 'Ε.60's & 70's(Α)''.
I can't for the love of god understand why the exception is thrown.

Comment: You should be using parametrized queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struggle continued when I got home to test the parameterized command. Eventually I found out what was causing the Exception.

OleDbCommand's are supposed to use '?' instead of a named '@param' parameter but I got it working both ways. Turns out the exception was thrown because I didn't wrap MusicCategory in square brackets.

The working syntax for the sql query is:

```
string select_cmd = "SELECT FileName FROM Song WHERE [MusicCategory] = ?"
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(select_cmd, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", category);
```

Answer (score 2):

The apostrophe's (`'`) inside of the category name is breaking out of the string in the query:

```
SELECT FileName FROM Songs WHERE MusicCategory='Ε.60's & 70's(Α)'
                                                    ^ this breaks out of the string
```

So you need to escape those characters

```
MusicCategory=\'" + category.Replace(@"'", @"''") + ...
```

However, this could easily have been resolved and made more robust by using parameters, which is the recommendation for putting user input values into a query.

```
string select_cmd = "Select FileNAme From songs where MusicCategory=@MusicCategory";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(select_cmd, con);
var prm = new OleDbParameter("@MusicCategory", category);
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
```

Comment: The string.replace method isn't working actually. I've done it with a parameterized command.